# Redirect Percentage of traffic to 2 different websites

Tags: javascript, redirect, traffic

I'm looking for a script that allows me to redirect users to 2 different websites.

Example scenario:
Users come to Site A, then 25% of them are redirected to Site B and 75% of them are redirected to Site C.

How can I achieve this? Should I use Javascript?

Comment: that's something the server will have to take care of, not your client.

Comment: why not? If it's my choice to redirect my users, I could also let them know.. BTW, how can I do it on the server side?

Comment: well..  the client doesn't know the server load, the server does. and it depends on what server technology you are using, or your hosting infrastructure.